# Sum of Stirling numbers of second kind $S(n,k)$ over $n$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, summation, stirling-numbers

I want to evaluate the sum:

$$E(a,n) = \sum_{i=a}^n S(i,a)$$

with $S(n,k)$ denoting the Stirling numbers of the second kind.
My problem is that as $n$ gets bigger this calculation gets quite computationally-expensive with either using the recursive definition

$$S(n+1,k) = kS(n,k)+S(n, k-1)$$

or the explicit formula

$$S(n,k)=\frac{1}{k!} \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^{k-j} {k \choose j} j^n$$

for $S$. 
So my question arises: is there a closed-form expression for $E$? If not, are there some sorts of other improvements to reduce the computational complexity of this sum?

Comment: For fixed $a$ the explicit formula for $S(i, a)$ reveals that it's a sum of $a+1$ different exponentials, so you can take the sum of a geometric series of each of these exponentials separately. This gives a reasonably nice approach if $a$ is small; are you primarily interested in $a$ small and $n$ large or are they both large for you?

Comment: $a$ would be in the region of $\sim 10^7$, which is not really _small_ if you look at it. But in comparison to $n$, which is $\sim 10^{12}$ you could say that $a$ is comparably _small_.

Comment: Do you need to compute exact values or would it be enough to have accurate asymptotics?

Comment: Exakt value modulo a prime. I need $E(a,n) \bmod 1000000007$. But i do not think that the modulo operation changes much in regards to the computational complexity. Since $a$ is so small compared to $n$ this sum takes pretty much $n$ iterations to calculate. Thus I think a closed-form expression for the sum is needed.

Comment: This seems like a coding problem. Can you refer us to it?

Answer (score 1):

For fixed $a$ the function $S(i, a)$ is a sum of various powers, so the partial sum over $i$ can be computed with a termwise sum of geometric series. That is, we have

$$E(n, a) = \sum_{i=a}^n \frac{1}{a!} \sum_{j=0}^a (-1)^{a-j} {a \choose j} j^i$$

(I am switching $a$ and $n$ in the input for $E$ to maintain consistency with $a$ being on the right for the Stirling numbers) and exchanging the order of the sum, as well as removing the $\frac{1}{a!}$, gives

$$E(n, a) = \frac{1}{a!} \sum_{j=0}^a  (-1)^{a-j} {a \choose j} \sum_{i=a}^n j^i.$$

The sum $\sum_{i=a}^n j^i$ is a geometric series $\frac{j^{n+1} - j^a}{j - 1}$, so this gives

$$E(n, a) = \frac{1}{a!} \sum_{j=0}^a (-1)^{a-j} {a \choose j} \frac{j^{n+1} - j^a}{j - 1}.$$

For fixed $a$ most of this expression doesn't depend on $n$ and so can be precomputed (I don't know if that's the case in your application though), and then we only need to compute the powers $j^{n+1}$. If you're working mod a prime this can be done very efficiently using [binary exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) and [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

Furthermore it sounds like in your application the prime is bigger than $a$, which allows us to make use of the observation that we can cancel the $a!$ factor from the binomial coefficients:

$$E(n, a) = \sum_{j=0}^a (-1)^{a-j} \frac{1}{j! (a - j)!} \frac{j^{n+1} - j^a}{j - 1}.$$

(The point being that we can compute $j! (a - j)! \bmod p$ and then invert it, without needing to keep track of a potentially large denominator that eventually cancels.) This should be a big save overall; we no longer have to perform any operation $n$ times.

Formally, to compute $j^{n+1} \bmod p$ we first reduce the exponent $\bmod (p-1)$; I'm not familiar with fast algorithms for dividing with remainder so I don't know how long this takes but probably not very long. This gives us a new exponent $m < p-1$ and then binary exponentiation will let us compute $j^m \bmod p$ in about $O(\log m) \le O(\log p)$ steps, and since $p = 10^9 + 7$ here this is not only constant but a pretty small constant!

Similar improvements are probably not available for the binomial coefficients / factorials but we still only have to do about $O(a)$ multiplications and we can work recursively and so forth, and computing inverses $\bmod p$ can be done efficiently using the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

Comment: This is a pretty nice optimization using the prime modulus. But if there is no closed-form expression of $E$ then I think that it is not really feasbile to calculate it. Even with your optimizations and getting it to $O(a)$, it would at least take $\mid 10^{12}$ iterations. But I am definetly going to try to implement it and see if it is feasible. Thanks for your time and effort, really appreciate it!